# Jquery AJAX POST without dataType and contentType

Tags: jquery, ajax

I had an AJAX call as follows:

```
I have an ajax get as follows:

        $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                data: model,
                dataType: "html",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

as my model had a large string, I changed it to POST as follows:

```
        $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: model,
                dataType: "html",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

I noticed that it could not reach the url properly so I removed dataType and contentType as follows:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: model,
                dataType: "html",
                ...
```

The above worked fine. Is there any danger is leaving out dataType and contentType when doing a POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you omit `dataType` it won't set an `Accept` header and will infer how to parse the response from the `Content-Type` *response* header.

If you don't set a `contentType`, it will set a default value for it based on the type of data you pass to `data`. Assuming `model` is a plain object, that will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format and the object will be encoded in that format.

---

It makes no sense to set `contentType` on a GET request: There is no request body to describe the content-type of.

Your code broke when you changed it to POST because you *weren't* sending JSON and the Content-Type *request* header became significant (because the data was now in the body).

Comment: Can you show how I should change the ajax call with a POST keeping contentType and datatype.

Comment: What `dataType` you use depends on what you expect to get back. What `contentType` you use depends on what format of data you are sending and you shouldn't explicitly set it unless you *need* to override the default behaviour … which you don't.